# Accessing a Profile in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to have the user (who is not signed in) be directed to the sign in page after clicking on "Your Profile"

[image]

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
  def user_profile
    render(:template => "profile/my_profile.html.erb")
  end
end
```

I tried to include  `before_action :authenticate_user!` inside my controller for the profile but I received an error:
`undefined method 'authenticate_user!'`

I have a separate controller for authenticating the user

Comment: Please provide what type of authentication are you using? Are you using devise or have you wrote your own authentication?

Comment: No I'm using another authentication code that was created from scratch.

Comment: You have to provide more details so people can understand the issue. like you can give the stack trace for the error and code block where error occured. Also, you can do this by redirect_to your_path_here if your_check_here.

Comment: Okay thanks. I think your last sentence is actually very helpful.

Comment: When you want to use the same method (`authenticate_user!` in this case) in multiple controllers, then you should move that method into the `application_controller.rb`. So that all other controllers inherit it from it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be having a method `authenticate_user!` either in `ProfileController` or `ApplicationController` itself. Then only you will be able to use it like this.

If you have it in another controller, you may copy it, or move it to a module concern and attach to the current/application controller.